# How to get time slots for a specific date

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-carbon

Hope all are doing well. I need to print an array as time slots.

Assume that there are 2 orders for `2021.11.15` on `11:30am to 12:00pm` and `2:00pm to 4:15pm`.

My order needs `1h 30m` to complete. Therefore time slots should be in between `8:00am and 6:00pm` skipping those times for already exist orders.

My expected results should be:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "start" => "08:00:00"
    "end" => "9:30:00"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "start" => "09:30:00"
    "end" => "11:00:00"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "start" => "12:00:00"
    "end" => "13:30:00"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "start" => "16:15:00"
    "end" => "17:45:00"
  ]
]
```

Following line is used to get exist orders object with their start and end times.

```
$existOrders = $this->orderHasPropartnerService->getOrderExistForDateProPartner($proPartnerDefaultLocation->id, $selectedDateRecord->date);
```

Then I just looped it.

```
if ($existOrders->count() > 0) {
                $dateStartTime = $selectedDateRecord->time_from;
                $x = 0;

                $firstEndingTime = Carbon::parse($dateStartTime)->addMinutes($totalTimeToOrder)->format('H:i:s');

                foreach ($existOrders as $key1 => $existOrder1) {

                    if ($existOrder1->order->time_slot_from < $firstEndingTime && $existOrder1->order->time_slot_to >= $firstEndingTime) {
                        $timeCheckArray[$x]['start'] = $existOrder1->order->time_slot_to;
                        $timeCheckArray[$x]['end'] = Carbon::parse($existOrder1->order->time_slot_to)->addMinutes($totalTimeToOrder)->format('H:i:s');
                    } else {
                        $timeSlotArray[$x]['start'] = $dateStartTime;
                        $timeSlotArray[$x]['end'] = $firstEndingTime;

                        $timeCheckArray[$x]['start'] = $firstEndingTime;
                        $timeCheckArray[$x]['end'] = Carbon::parse($firstEndingTime)->addMinutes($totalTimeToOrder)->format('H:i:s');
                    }

                    if (isset($existOrders[$key1+1])) {
                        if ($existOrders[$key1+1]->order->time_slot_from < $timeCheckArray[$x]['end'] && $existOrders[$key1+1]->order->time_slot_to >= $timeCheckArray[$x]['end']) {

                        } else {
                            $timeSlotArray[$x+1]['start'] = $timeCheckArray[$x]['start'];
                            $timeSlotArray[$x+1]['end'] = $timeCheckArray[$x]['end'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

As for the above example `$dateStartTime` will be `8:00am`. Value of `$totalTimeToOrder` will be `1h 30m`.

When I try to print `$timeSlotArray` it'll result as follows:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "start" => "08:00:00"
    "end" => "09:30:00"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "start" => "08:00:00"
    "end" => "09:30:00"
  ]
]
```

It is really appreciated if someone point me out where I did mistakes in this logic. Thank you so much guys for your valuable time for a problem of mine.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to run a for loop to check that the New order does not fall between the booked times .

Try something similar to this by converting it to a PHP Date object

```
$NewOrder= "4:59 pm";
$start= "5:42 am";
$end= "6:26 pm";

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', $NewOrder);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', $start);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', $end);
if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3)
{
   echo 'Not safe to add it ';
}
```

Comment: If the time in between those two dates I can stay by not adding it. But how I manage to get the time as start time should be the previous order's ending time. And also new order is not a time in clock. It is a time of needed. Thank you so much for your answer @JonoJames